# Delete and Insert Rows crashing when there are a large amount of cells

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, tableview, performbatchupdates

I am having an issue with table view cell insertion and deletion. I basically have 1 tableView that can display 3 different arrays in it, based on a mode selected by the user.

When the user clicks on a different mode, I want to animate the initial cell removal and then animate the insertion of the other cells.

This is working when my arrays are really small (size of 5 or so) but when it gets larger than that I get crashes. Are we restricted from removing indexPaths that aren't on display in tableViews?

Anyway my code is as follows:

```
 func viewDidLoad() {
    let o1 = "1"
    let o2 = "2"
    let o3 = "3"
    array1 = [o1, o2, o2, o1, o3, o1, o2] 
    array2 = [o3, o2, o2, o1, o3, o1, o2, o2, o2, o1, o3, o1, o2]
    array3 = [o3, o1, o2, o2, o2, o1, o3, o1, o2]
}

func animateTableTransitions() {
    let array: [String]!
    let previousArray: [String]!
    let index = ModeEnum.index
    let previousIndex = ModeEnum.index //Custom enum that mains the index at which each mode is presented
    var indexPaths = [IndexPath]()
    var previousIndexPaths = [IndexPath]()
    switch (currentMode, previousMode) {
    case (.mode1, .mode2):
        array = array1
        previousArray = array2
    case (.mode1, .mode3):
        array = array1
        previousArray = array3
    case (.mode2, .mode1):
        array = array2
        previousArray = array1
    case (.mode2, .mode3):
        array = array2
        previousArray = array3
    case (.mode3, .mode1):
        array = array3
        previousArray = array1
    case (.mode3, .mode2):
        array = array3
        previousArray = array2
    default:
        return
    }

    for index in 0..<array.count {
        indexPaths.append(IndexPath(row: index, section: 0))
    }

    for index in 0..<previousArray.count {
        previousIndexPaths.append(IndexPath(row: index, section: 0))
    }

    if previousTranslationMode == .text && textModeOn {
        previousIndexPaths.append(IndexPath(item: textArray.count, section: 0))
    }

    let firstAnimationType: UITableViewRowAnimation = index < previousIndex ? .right : .left
    let secondAnimationType: UITableViewRowAnimation = index < previousIndex ? .left : .right

    tableView.performBatchUpdates({
        self.tableView.deleteRows(at: previousIndexPaths, with: firstAnimationType)
        self.tableView.insertRows(at: indexPaths, with: secondAnimationType)
    }, completion: nil)
```

As stated, when the arrays don't populate that many items, no issue is occurring. But i'm having an issue when the arrays are populated with what seems to be more than 5 items. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you for your time, 
Alan

Comment: Please edit your question to include the exception details. What are the exception messages? Which line does it crash on?  Why are you enumerating the items in the array and then searching the array for the item?  Why not use a simple numeric loop from `0..<array.count`?

Comment: Will do. As for your last question, the answer is that it's a stupid mistake haha. Thank you for your comment

Comment: @Paulw11 it seems that after updating the enumeration I stopped getting crashes for some reason. I'm sure there is something else at play but can't seem to figure it out. Anyway though, as of now it is working